# Using constraints across multiple edges in OrientDB

Tags: orientdb

I have a use case where I have 3 nodes connected by 2 edges.

In the example below, how can I constrain the relationship between the nodes so that I can only traverse the graph from A1 to C1 and A2 to C2 but I shouldn't be able to go from A1 to C2 or A2 to C1.

> A1 <--edge--> B1 <--edge--> C1
>
> A2 <--edge--> B1 <--edge--> C2

Example use case:

Character(A) PlayedBy(edge) Actor(B) In(edge) Movie(C)

where multiple characters can by played by a single actor in multiple movies but not all characters appeared in all movies linked by the actor. It's a many to one to many relationship where A is also linked to C.

Comment: I'm not sure about what you want.
Give a result example of what you want the query return.